# How to simplify this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there a nicer way to do the same ?

```
objects = []
outer_h.values.each do |inner_h|
  inner_h.values.each do |obj|
    objects << obj
  end
end
```

I use Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question and added a sample of the data structure you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objects = outer_h.values.map(&:values).flatten` will work:

```
h = {
  1 => { :foo => "bar", :bar => "baz" },
  2 => { :foo => "rab", :bar => "zab" },
}

h.values.map(&:values).flatten  #=> ["bar", "baz", "rab", "zab"]
```

Comment: And if using ruby 1.9.2, simplify it with `flat_map`.

Answer (score 0):

How about outer_h.flatten ? I think it might only work for arrays though.